# How do I measure initiated SSL connections per second on IIS?

Tags: iis, performance-monitoring, perfmon, f5-big-ip

I am running a stress test on a web application that is being proxied by IIS/Win2008R2 and want to measure the number of SSL Transactions Per Second going across it.

In production I have a F5 load balancer that throttles connections to its license limit, so it will reject new SSL connections in excess of 20 (new connections created) per 10ms sliding window.

I want to measure SSL connections in a 10ms sliding window or at least within a 10ms window (or worse case, a few seconds window).

Is there any way to achieve this with perfmon? I have not found any.

Is there any way to achieve this using something else? I am thinking wireshark perhaps...

What would you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a test environment as you describe, and you limit requests to only SSL (ie disable http binding, leaving only the SSL binding) you can use the existing current connection counters to measure your SSL TPS.